# Change jquery mobile data-type (between horizontal and vertical)

Tags: jquery-mobile, type-conversion

May I know if i can change the data-type='horizontal' of the controlgroup data-role into data-type="vertical" while my orientation of my ipad is changed??

Is it something due with $("div").attr() or $("div").css() ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change something on orientation change use:

```
$(window).bind("orientationchange", function(){
    if(window.orientation != 0){
        // Do something when sideways
    }else{
        // Do something when normal
    }
});
```

Good luck!